# Is it possible to get (feed) Facebook posts multilingual?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Since a while its possible to post on Facebook multilingual:
https://code.facebook.com/posts/597373993776783/building-a-better-way-to-write-posts-in-multiple-languages/

I'm posting on my page in German and English and I wanna integrate my Facebook posts on a website. If you use the website English, I wanna present them the English versions of my posts.

So, I try to get the posts multilinugal, but I couldn't find any option in the Graph API Explorer. The posts always show up in the default language.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Is it possible to get (feed) Facebook posts multilingual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `locale` parameter for that, 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#readmodifiers:

> locale
>   Used if your app needs the ability to retrieve localized content in the language of a particular locale (when available).

If the post is available in the requested locale, you will get that one returned - otherwise, the “default” language version of the post.

Comment: Got it :) Thanks a lot